# Python3- fail to find `paho` module

Tags: python

I have a python code to operate using `paho-mqtt`, which run OK from command line, but when I try to run it as service during boot process, it fails.

looking in `/var/log/daemon.log` shows that it fails since it does not find module.

```
Jul 20 09:13:34 HomePi_Win1 python3[208]:   File "/home/guy/github/RemoteSwitch/mqtt_switch.py", line 3, in <module>
Jul 20 09:13:34 HomePi_Win1 python3[208]:     import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
Jul 20 09:13:34 HomePi_Win1 python3[208]: ImportError: No module named 'paho'
```

not liking solutions as adding path in code:

```
from sys import path
path.append('/home/guy/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paho')
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from threading import Thread
import time
```

BUT - still got the same message.

What else can be done ?

Comment: it seems like the problem is with your local environment, it doesn't get packages from global site-package list.

Comment: @Mr.J - but to solve it, I added a spcific path when it should be found ( DONT like it ), but still- it fails.

Comment: check if that path actually accessible. try to add path in PYTHONPATH environment variable.